# knockoutjs function to set the href url with parameters

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to be able to set the url of a hyperlink programatically in knockoutjs, this is what I'm doing:

```
self.openOrderHref = function (order) {
            return "OrderDetails.aspx?action=view&OrderNumber=" + order.OrderNumber;
        };
```

And in the html I have:

```
> <a data-bind="attr: { href: $root.openOrderHref }"
> class="gradient-button action">Details</a>
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

The result at this moment is:

> http://localhost:5043/Underclass/function%20%28order%29%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22OrderDetails.aspx?action=view&OrderNumber=%22%20+%20order.OrderNumber;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}

Comment: `openOrderHref` is a function with one argument `order`, but you use it in your binding without any argument.. are you meant `data-bind="attr: { href: $root.openOrderHref($data) }"`?

Comment: You are setting `href` to the function, not executing the function. Use a `ko.computed` property.

Comment: @MattBurland can you please explain how can I do that ,thx

Comment: @nemesv yes, please put that as your answer, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `openOrderHref` is a function which has one argument `order`, however you are using it in your binding without any argument so KO will use your whole function definition as a string as the link's `href`

To solve this you need to pass in something to your function. Presumably your link is inside a `foreach` binding where `$data` is representing the currently iterated item in the loop, so you can just write:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: $root.openOrderHref($data) }" 
   class="gradient-button action">Details</a>
```